# RDOMail unable to change BodyFormat property

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-redemption, outlook-2013

I couldn't change property BodyFormat of RDOMail object from plain text to html. 
I have the following code:

```
RDOMail rdoMessage = rdoFolder.Items.Add("FooType");
```

`rdoMessage.Subject = "Subject";`

Also I'm adding some user properties here.

The next line of code not works properly. BodyFormat property stays equal to    olFormatPlain(1), instead of olFormatHTML (2).

```
rdoMessage.BodyFormat = (int)rdoBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the RDOMail.BodyFormat property, Redemption simply sets the PR_MSG_EDITOR_FORMAT proprety. It will not convert the message body to a different format.

To have an HTML message, you actually need to set the RDOMail.HTMLBody property to a properly formatted HTML string.